# What happened to the budding TV series "Space Command"?

Tags: tv

I was [reading](https://www.looper.com/191120/what-the-cast-of-babylon-5-is-doing-today/) about what the cast of Babylon 5 was doing recently, and stumbled onto a TV show called [Space Command](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2404379/) that some of them were involved with. Delenn (Mira Furlan - I can't help it) was involved in this show until her death earlier this year from West Nile virus. So was Bill Mumy. There's also a continuing favorite - Robert Picardo (the doctor from Voyager).

[IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2404379/episodes?season=1&ref_=tt_eps_sn_1) shows a series of episodes, but it looks like only a few of them might have been produced. Does anyone know if Space Command died (due to Covid-19?), or whether additional episodes are planned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there was a [kickstarter for episode 4](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/spacecommand/space-command-forgiveness-chapter-4/description) "Forgiveness, Part 2" that just closed on July 27th, so I imagine that it's currently in the works.

The [2021 plan](https://spacecommand-theseries.com/the-coming-year-2021/) was for shooting episode 4 in August, and based on the timeline of the previous episodes it will take at least a month for the effects and post-production; their plan suggests it will be completed sometime around October.  Note, however, the plan was also for the kickstarter campaign in May, so they may be running a couple of months behind.

There haven't been any negative updates so far, and they just finished raising money, so I'd expect that episodes 3/4 will drop some time this year or early next.